# Confusion with Telerik/Kendo function declaration syntax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I inherited an ASP.Net MVC 3 project using Telerik controls. I'm updating everything to Kendo UI. The issue I'm having applies to both Telerik and Kendo when chaining functions onto a grid (or any other) control.

In all code examples on telerik/kendo sites, I see the following when declaring, say, a grid:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<QuotationItemViewModel>()
          .Name("quotationProductsGrid")
          .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(p => p.ID))
```

However, in my inherited project, the same code would be written this way:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid<QuotationItemViewModel>()
          .Name("quotationProductsGrid")
          .DataKeys(Function(dataKeys) dataKeys.Add(Function(p) p.ID))
```

When attempting to chain additional functions - or just modify the existing - the `keys => keys.Add(p => p.ID)` syntax throws '*keys* is not declared' error.

Can someone explain or provide documentation on the differences in syntax and why `Function(datakeys) dataKeys.Add(Function(p) p.ID)` may have been used? Does it have to do with how the code was imbedded into the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code is C# (see [Lambda Expressions (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx)) while the second example is in Visual Basic (see [Lambda Expressions (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)). The correct programming language syntax needs to be used or, as discovered, syntax errors will abound.

The syntax presented is *functionally equivalent* and has nothing to do with Telerik/Kendo (and *much less* to do with anything client-side); rather, the correct choice of syntax is tied directly to the language (e.g. C#/VB.NET) used for the page view.

The language used for the page is controlled by the [@Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) directive's Language attribute.

Comment: Thank you! I knew this was a noob question.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to look at the @Page directive (especially when working in mixed-language projects).